# Images and magnification

Tags: javascript, html, css

My new computer has a 2880x1800 pixel resolution and a screen magnification of 175% - now what I notice on our corporate web page is that the company logo has become very pixelated. How can we "detect" with pure CSS or HTML to show a higher resolution logo when visitors have a high resultion screen and screen magnification? Must we rely on Javascript - and is it even possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 1500px)" href="1500.css" />
```

which would only target devices with > 1500px horizontal resolution.

Detecting the browser zoom isn't so simple. I think [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers) adequately handles it.

Comment: The SO link has a link to a JS library https://github.com/yonran/detect-zoom that seems useful, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an easy problem to solve. You have several options. Here is Chris Coyier's [roundup](http://css-tricks.com/on-responsive-images/).

Personally, I would follow [Dave Rupert](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/mo-pixels-mo-problems/)'s method of using an image that is about 1.5 times the size it is being displayed. It's certainly the easiest and sanest solution.

```
img {width: 200px; height: 200px;}​

<img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nYpqf/)